# MSI product property information

Tags: c++, windows, wix, windows-installer

I have following xml for wix configuration of the MSI..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
         xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UIExtension">
    <Product Id="*"
        Name="MyProductName"
        Language="1033"
        Version="1.0.0"
        Manufacturer="Stack"
        Codepage="1200"
        UpgradeCode="242C9452-1B5E-414A-8245-D86B14E8E9CC">


        <Package Id="*"
            InstallerVersion="405"
            Compressed="yes"
            InstallScope="perMachine"
            Description="MyProduct"
        />

        <Property Id="Company" Value="$(var.Company)"/>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

And I am using below code (QT C++) to code to get the property information

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Msi.h>
#include <MsiQuery.h>

LPCWSTR program = L"C:/installer.msi";
MSIHANDLE hProduct = NULL;
LPWSTR pszVersion = NULL;
LPDWORD dwSizeVersion = NULL;
LPCWSTR property = L"ProductVersion";

MsiOpenPackage( program, &hProduct );
MsiGetProductProperty( hProduct, property, pszVersion, dwSizeVersion );
MsiCloseHandle( hProduct );

qDebug() << "MSI Property version is : " << QString::fromWCharArray(pszVersion);
```

I have tried adding ProductVersion to field property in the code, but the code is not returning the value provided in the XML. How can I get the Product Version, Package InstallVersion and Company property information from the MSI.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that your last parameter should be the size of the buffer where the result is going to be stored, not NULL.